# How to keep a consistent order to eigenvalues of a matrix using numpy or scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, physics

I am trying to get a plot of a set of eigenvalues of a matrix against a detuning factor epsilon. I want the plot to look like this
[Matlab Plot using eig()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPVgT.png)

However when I use `np.linalg.eigvals` I get the following
[Python eigvals plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mux6j.png)

I also tried using `np.linalg.eigvalsh` which gave [Python eigvalsh plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo4Ws.png).

The problem seems to be how the eigenvalues are ordered upon the return for the function. I was wondering if there's any way to get it so I produce plot lines like in the first image from matlab. I've also tried the equivalent scipy functions which just gave the same as the numpy.

Here is a copy of my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu = 57.88e-3
eps = np.linspace(-0.26,0.26,100)

def Model_g1g2(g1, g2, B, t):
   
    E = np.empty([len(eps), 5])  # Initialise array for eigenvalues
    for i in range(len(eps)):
        # Matrix A
        A = np.array([[(-eps[i]+(g1+g2)*mu*B)/2, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                  [0, -eps[i]/2, 0, (g1-g2)*mu*B, 0],
                  [0, 0, (-eps[i]-(g1+g2)*mu*B)/2, 0, 0],
                  [0, (g1-g2)*mu*B/2, 0, -eps[i]/2, t],
                  [0, 0, 0, t, eps[i]/2]
                  ])

        E[i,:] = np.linalg.eigvals(A) # Store eigenvalues
    return E

E = Model_g1g2(1, 4, 0.5, 0.06)

# Produce Plot
for i in range(5):
    plt.plot(eps, np.real(E[:,I]))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab, the eigenvalues are sorted.

Change `E[i,:] = np.linalg.eigvals(A)` to `E[i,:] = sorted(np.linalg.eigvals(A))`, then you'll get what you want.